# Jquery dataTables using filter on updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a jquery mobile app that consist of a table.
The table contains a time field and some numerical field.
They stats are static as the do not change and i am able to filter the table by name or numbers.Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynKed/8/)

Then i decided to increment the table values as displayed in this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ynKed/10/).

Code for updating values

```
function UpdateFunction(){
    $(".updateMeInt").each(function(index){
       var cur = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
       $(this).text(cur + 1);    
    });

    $(".updateMeTime").each(function(index){
        var cur = $(this).text().split(":");    
        var sec = parseInt(cur[1], 10);        
        var min = parseInt(cur[0], 10);

        sec = sec + 3;
        if (sec >= 60){
             sec = 0
             min = min + 1;
        }
        $(this).text(pad(min) + ":" + pad(sec)); 

    });
}  

function pad(num) {
    var s = "0" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-2);
}
```

However the issue is now i can't filter for the updated values.

Can someone please advice as to why this is and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `dataTable` as well as the `html`.

for example, ammend your function to update the integer cells:

```
$(".updateMeInt").each(function(index)
{
    var cur = 1+ parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();       

    oTable.fnUpdate(cur, $(this).parent('tr')[0], $(this).index());
});
```

in the above, `fnUpdate` ([see docos](http://datatables.net/api)) is being passed the new cell value, the parent `tr`-element and the cell-index.

[Here's a fork](http://jsfiddle.net/PN4j2/) of your second jsfiddle.

But you will now probably notice that once you filter the content, only the visible rows continue to update. It may be that you are planning to get your dynamic data from an `ajax` call or something; in which case you might be better off totally destroying the old `dataTable` on an update.

Nevertheless, as per your current example, the following `UpdateFunction()` should also update *filtered* rows hiding in the `dataTable`:

```
function UpdateFunction()
{
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var nNodes = oTable.fnGetNodes();

    $.each(nNodes, function(index,node)
    {
        $(node).children(".updateMeInt").each(function(index)
        {
           var cur = 1+ parseInt($(this).text(), 10);       
           oTable.fnUpdate(cur,node,$(this).index());
        });            

        $(node).children(".updateMeTime").each(function(index)
        {
            var cur = $(this).text().split(":");    
            var sec = 3+ parseInt(cur[1], 10);        
            var min = parseInt(cur[0], 10);

            if (sec >= 60)
            {
                min+=1;
                sec%=60;
            }

            var newval=pad(min) + ":" + pad(sec);
            oTable.fnUpdate(newval,node,$(this).index());
        });            
    });
}
```

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/XEwbU/) in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi i have posted a new question i am very much stuck on this can u please help as ur good with datatables.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938579/sorting-and-searching-datatables-after-refreshing-table