# Sorting and Searching DataTables after refreshing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

**BACKGROUND:** 
I have a small jquery app that contains widgets. There are 2 types of widgets in this app and they are counter widgets and grid widgets. For grid widgets i am utilizing [dataTables](https://datatables.net/).

My app basically connects to a server and recieves various information such as widget names and values for the counter and grid widgets. So based on the information received i dynamically create pages for each widget. Things are working fine at the moment but i am facing a little problem.

**Problem** 
The issue i have right now is to do with my grid widgets which utilize dataTables api.From my server I receive the grid information in this format.

```
**//EXAMPLE INPUT
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <head>
        <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Player</column>
        <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">State</column>
        <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Points</column>
    </head>
     <row id="1">
        <cell>Lebron King James</cell>
        <cell>Best Mode</cell>
        <cell>45</cell>
     </row>
</rows>
*/**
```

I then parse this and insert it in the tables. The problem is i am doing a update every 3 seconds since the data for grid gets updated in real time . So when i do a update my search filter and sorting is reset.

So for example below if i am sorting by highest points

```
PLAYER         POINTS
KING JAMES     45
DERRICK ROSE   30 

UPDATE HAPPENS AND MY SORTING WILL GET REST TO THIS

PLAYER         POINTS
DERRICK ROSE    30
KING JAMES      45
```

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <title>
      NBA Fanatico
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/tdMobile.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfinal/style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dhtmxSuite/dhtmlxWindows/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- MAIN JS SCRIPT CONTANS CODE FOR COUTNER WIDGETS, TABLES , AJAX REQUEST FOR GETTING DATA-->
    <script src="dynamic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- SCRIPTS FOR DATA TABLES -->
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" /><!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- PAGE 1 -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1">
      <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="login-box" id="login">
          <div id="loginprompt">
            <div id="header">
              <h3>
                Basketball Fanatico
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form method="get">
            <div id="username" data-role="fieldcontain">
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div id="password" data-role="fieldcontain">
              <input type="password" name="password" id="txtId" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div id="loginbtn">
              <a data-role="button" id="log" data-theme="a" href="#page2" data-transition="slide">LOGIN</a>
            </div>
          </form><br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- PAGE 2 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars"></a>
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">
          Basketball Fanatico
        </h1>
        <div class="ui-btn-right" data-type="horizontal">
          <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="home"></a> <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page1" data-role="button" data-icon="delete"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" id="page2content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a">WELCOME!
          </li>
          <li>Use the menu on the left to navigate<br />
            and configure the various options.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel" data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="push">
      <!--  <div> -->
      <div id="nav">
        <h3>
          Navigation
        </h3>
        <hr />
        <label><input id="chkSort" type="checkbox" checked="true" />Allow sorting</label>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div id="items" data-role="button">
        <!-- Insert Parsed Widget Names Here -->
        <a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-theme="a" data-role="button">LOG OUT</a>
      </div><!-- </div> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MY JS**

```
var widgetNames = new Array();
var widgetId = new Array();
var pageId = ''

$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("body > [data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();
});

$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function () {
    $("#log").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "script.login",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'page': 'create_user',
                'access': 'user',
                'username': $("input[name='username']").val(),
                'password': $("input[name='password']").val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (html) {
                widgetNames = new Array();
                widgetId = new Array();
                var res = html.match(/insertNewChild(.*);/g);
                //Get each widget name and ID and assign to values in an array
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    //alert(res[i]);
                    var temp = res[i].split(',');
                    if (temp.length >= 3) {
                        widgetNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");', '')).replace('"', '');
                        widgetId[i] = temp[1].replace("'", "").replace("'", "").replace(/ /g, '');
                    }
                }
                var AllWidgets = ''
                var testwidget = new Array();
                //Loop through the html returned and get the data relevant to each widget... save in temp array                            
                var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);
                for (var i = 0; i < tempWidgetContent.length; i++) {
                    var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{') + 1);
                    testwidget[i] = widgetContent.replace("site +", "");
                    //replace the code for a grids...
                    if (testwidget[i].indexOf('grid') > 0) {
                        testwidget[i] = CreateGridUpdateFunction(testwidget[i], i);
                    }
                }

                var widgetPart = new Array();
                //Assume we have widget names, ids, and loading data in 3 arrays
                //Loop through and create the necessary page.
                for (var i = 0; i < widgetNames.length; i++) {
                    if (testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1) {
                        //Header FOR grid Widget Page
                        var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role= 'page' id='" + widgetId[i] + "' data-pageindex='" + i + "' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' id='header1' data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a href='#panel' data-icon='bars' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left'></a><a href='#' data-icon='search' id='search' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-left' style='margin-left: 35px'></a><h1>Basketball Fanatico</h1><a href='#page1' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right'></a><a href='#page2' data-icon='home' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' style='margin-right: 35px;'></a></div><div data-role='content'>";
                    } else {
                        //Header For Counter Widget Page
                        var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role='page' id='" + widgetId[i] + "' data-pageindex='" + i + "' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header'data-position='fixed' data-theme='a'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button'data-icon='bars'></a><h1 class='ui-title'role='heading'>Basketball Fanatico</h1><div class='ui-btn-right' data-type='horizontal'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button'data-icon='home'style=\" margin-right:5px; \"></a><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page1' data-role='button'data-icon='delete'></a></div></div><div data-role='content'>";
                    }

                    //Footer for all Widget Pages
                    var pageFooterPart = "</div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>";

                    if (testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1) {
                        //Grid Page widget title
                        var check = "<div data-role='tbcontent'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>" + widgetNames[i] + "";
                    }

                    //Counter Page widget title
                    var check = "<div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='a'>" + widgetNames[i] + "</div>";

                    if (testwidget[i].indexOf('counterValue') > 0) {
                        //Counter Content (actual value of the counter widget)
                        widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#EDEDED; padding-bottom: auto;  font-size: 55pt;\" id=widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv' + widgetId[i] + '() {' + testwidget[i] + '$(\"#widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '").html(counterValue);' + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';

                    }
                    if (testwidget[i].indexOf('hi') > -1) {
                        //Grid content(actual values for the grid widget)     
                        widgetPart[i] = '<DIV id=widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv' + widgetId[i] + '() {' + testwidget[i] + '}' + '</SCRIPT>';
                    } else {

                        //Miscalenous content(these are counter widgets that will contain text messages for now just putting "i dont know what i am")
                        widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#EDEDED; padding-bottom: auto;  font-size: 55pt;\" id=widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '>I dont know what I am</DIV>';
                    }

                    AllWidgets += '<a href="#' + widgetId[i] + '" class="widgetLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >' + widgetNames[i] + '</a>';
                    var makePage = $(pageHeaderPart + check + widgetPart[i] + pageFooterPart);
                    makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                }
                $('#items').prepend(AllWidgets).trigger('create');

                //Widget Update Function
                function UpdateActivePage() {
                    //get active page
                    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");
                    //figure out index
                    var idx;
                    for (var i = 0; i < widgetId.length; i++) {
                        if (widgetId[i] == pageId) {
                            idx = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    eval(testwidget[idx]);
                    $("#widgetContainer_" + pageId).html(counterValue);

                    $('#grid_' + idx).dataTable({
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "oLanguage": {
                            "sSearch": ""
                        }
                    });
                    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
                    $('.dataTables_filter').css('float', 'none');
                    $('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right', '0px');
                    $("#example_filter").detach().prependTo('#header1');
                }

                function CreateGridUpdateFunction(oldUpdatefunction, thisWidgetID) {
                    var updateLines = oldUpdatefunction.split("\n");
                    var updateFunctionCode = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < updateLines.length; i++) {
                        if (updateLines[i].indexOf(" var url = ") > 0) {
                            //alert(updateLines[i]);
                            //    updateFunctionCode = " try { ";
                            var updateURL = updateLines[i];
                            if (updateURL.indexOf("&windowWidth=") > 0) {
                                updateURL = updateURL.substr(0, updateURL.lastIndexOf("&windowWidth=")) + "';";
                                //console.log(updateURL);
                            }
                            updateFunctionCode += updateURL;
                            updateFunctionCode += "   var loader = dhtmlxAjax.getSync(url);";
                            updateFunctionCode += "   if(loader.xmlDoc.responseText.length > 0){";
                            updateFunctionCode += "     counterValue = createTableStringFromXML(loader.xmlDoc.responseText," + thisWidgetID + ");";
                            updateFunctionCode += "   }   ";
                        }
                    }
                    return "var counterValue = \"hi\"; " + updateFunctionCode;
                }

                $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on("pagechange", function () {
                    UpdateActivePage();
                })

                setInterval(UpdateActivePage, 3000);
            }
        });
    });
});

 //Returns a bool indicated if the (space trimmed) string starts with needle.
function startsWith(searchString, searchVal) {
    var search = searchString.trim();
    return search.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0;
}

function createTableStringFromXML(serverXML, thisWidgetID) {
    //EXAMPLE INPUT
    /*
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <rows>
            <head>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Player</column>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">State</column>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Points</column>
            </head>
            <row id="1">
                <cell>Lebron James</cell>
                <cell>Injured</cell>
                <cell>25 </cell>
            </row>
        </rows>
    */
    console.log(serverXML);
    //PARSE THE ABOVE XML STRING to required FORMAT
    var xmlLines = serverXML.split("\n");
    var returnTable = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < xmlLines.length; i++) {
        if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<rows")) {
            returnTable += "<table cellpadding=\"2\"  cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"0\" class=\"display\" id=\"grid_" + thisWidgetID + "\" width=\"100%\">";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</rows>")) {
            returnTable += "</tbody></table>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<head>")) {
            returnTable += "<thead><tr>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</head>")) {
            returnTable += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<column")) {
            returnTable += "<th>" + xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1] + "</th>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<row")) {
            returnTable += "<tr>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</row")) {
            returnTable += "</tr>";
        } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<cell")) {
            returnTable += "<td>" + xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1] + "</td>";
        }
        console.log(returnTable);
    }
    return returnTable;
}
```

Please advice on how to fix this i have been stuck on this for one week now almost i am sorry if this question is bad as i am only few months new to js and html and web development in general. I apologize for my poor English also.

**UPDATED CODE BY EZ**

See comments that start with `//EZ`:

```
                function UpdateActivePage() {
                    //get active page
                    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");
                    //figure out index
                    var idx;
                    for (var i = 0; i < widgetId.length; i++) {
                        if (widgetId[i] == pageId) {
                            idx = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }   
                    eval(testwidget[idx]);

                    if (counterValue == false) {
                        //EZ: no need to recreate datatable
                        return;
                    } else {
                        $("#widgetContainer_" + pageId).html(counterValue);

                        $('#grid_' + idx).dataTable({
                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "bFilter": true,
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "oLanguage": {
                                "sSearch": ""
                            }
                        });
                        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search");
                        $('.dataTables_filter').css('float', 'none');
                        $('.dataTables_filter').css('padding-right', '0px');
                        $("#example_filter").detach().prependTo('#header1');
                    }
                }


function createTableStringFromXML(serverXML, thisWidgetID) {
    //EXAMPLE INPUT
    /*
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <rows>
            <head>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Player</column>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">State</column>
                <column width="55" type="ro" align="left" sort="str">Points</column>
            </head>
            <row id="1">
                <cell>Lebron James</cell>
                <cell>Injured</cell>
                <cell>25 </cell>
            </row>
        </rows>
    */
    console.log(serverXML);
    //PARSE THE ABOVE XML STRING to required FORMAT
    var xmlLines = serverXML.split("\n");
    var returnTable = "";

    //EZ: See if table already exists
    if ( $("#grid_" + thisWidgetID).length > 0){
        //EZ: update table using the datatables API...

        //EZ: then return false 
        return false;
    } else {

        for (var i = 0; i < xmlLines.length; i++) {
            if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<rows")) {
                returnTable += "<table cellpadding=\"2\"  cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"0\" class=\"display\" id=\"grid_" + thisWidgetID + "\" width=\"100%\">";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</rows>")) {
                returnTable += "</tbody></table>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<head>")) {
                returnTable += "<thead><tr>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</head>")) {
                returnTable += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<column")) {
                returnTable += "<th>" + xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1] + "</th>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<row")) {
                returnTable += "<tr>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "</row")) {
                returnTable += "</tr>";
            } else if (startsWith(xmlLines[i], "<cell")) {
                returnTable += "<td>" + xmlLines[i].match(/>(.*?)</i)[1] + "</td>";
            }
            console.log(returnTable);
        }
    }
    return returnTable;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatables has a rich api (http://datatables.net/api) that provides for adding, deleting, and updating rows while keeping the sorting. In your case, the new data might require deleting rows that are no longer in the XML, updating existing rows, and adding new rows that are in the XML but not in the table.

Probably the easiest thing would be to call fnClearTable to remove all current rows and use fnAddData to add all the rows in the XML:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
oTable.fnClearTable();

$xml.find("row").each(function(index){            
    var $cells = $(this).find("cell");
    var c1 = $cells.eq(0).text();
    var c2 = $cells.eq(1).text();
    var c3 = $cells.eq(2).text();

    oTable.fnAddData( [c1, c2, c3]);
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9q7ve/2/)**

Comment: Hi, I tried to integrate the code you showed in fiddle to my original code and faced issues. From what i understand...on an every update i just have to clear table using fnClearTable() and then add the new xml data using fnAddData. However i wasnt sure where i would add this in my code...is it possible for you to make suggestions?I know you found my code hard to read so i commented a lot of it so if you can take a look at the updated js code above and guide me i would really appreciate. Thanks a lot i am very close to finishing this .

Comment: Maybe in createTableStringFromXML you can test to see if the table is already there, if it is update instead of create. Then in UpdateActivePage only initialize the datatable if it does not already exist...

Comment: what do you mean by update? i thought u suggested that we clear the table and then add data again for every update..is it possible to show what u said by code? i will understand better..u can update my js if u want. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, by update I mean use the datatables api to clear all rows and then add rows. I can't edit your code because I cannot understand it.  On your update interval, you can see if the table already exists: if ($("#grid_" + theWidgetID).length > 0){} then you can use the apis instead of creating from scratch.

Comment: okay and also u know how in your fiddle u use             oTable.fnAddData( [c1, c2, c3]); in that u know that u have 3 columns but i dont know in mine since it can vary from time to time so how would i take care of this issue?

Comment: hi thanks again, i am still struggling for some reason i tried to follow what u told me . is it possible if i breakdown of whats happening in my code more to u might be able to better assist me?

Comment: The script you build in CreateGridUpdateFunction(), does it only run when you update the grid every 3 seconds, or also to create the grid the first time?

Comment: sorry meant to write it runs the first time when grid is created.

Comment: it is not required to run after.

Comment: oh, i assumed the updateFunctionCode inside CreateGridUpdateFunction is what gets run every 3 seconds, if not what code is actually run every 3 seconds(eval(testwidget[idx]);)?

Comment: yes that is the one running every 3 seconds since it is inside updateactivepage function which is called to run every 3 seconds.

Comment: so the eval runs createTableStringFromXML which sets counterValue and then you replace the HTML with counterValue and init the datatable.  You need to rewrite that to run the datatables api calls instead of returning and replacing the HTML.

Comment: yea i believe i tried this earlier perhaps i might have done it wrong is it possible to show in the js code?btw just in general is this too much processing being done at once?

Comment: you will have to see if the devices you plan to support can handle it.  There is no general guideline, just test the software and optimize as needed.

Comment: Maybe in createTableStringFromXML if table already exists, update via api and set counterValue to false, then in UpdateActivePage if counterValue is false, don't set HTML or init datatable. That way only the first time UpdateActivePage runs it will create the table markup from scratch...

Comment: i tried but getting error again. =/ is it possible for to edit code n show in my js code that way if i have something to work with it i can go from there. i would really appreciate it.

Comment: i posted some updated code at the end of your original post. My comments start with //EZ:. My changes only make sense if I understand your code, so it is possible I am missing some consequence of my changes...

Comment: okay now that makes some sense and for the part where i update using api i first do clear using the following right  
var oTable = $('#grid_'+idx).dataTable();
        oTable.fnClearTable();

Comment: only question is how do i use the fnAddData Function?

Comment: sorry thats a mistake i did this ==> 

var oTable = $("#grid_" + thisWidgetID).dataTable();
        oTable.fnClearTable();

Comment: so now the table is initally created and then after update it is cleared which makes sense. now question is how to use fnAddData function.

Comment: Do what I did in the fiddle. If serverXML is a string, var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( serverXML ); var $xml = $( xmlDoc ); $xml.find("row").each(function(index){...

Comment: hey i had a small question i forked ur fiddle and created this. i basically trying to put the search button where it says "basketball fanatico" so basically on clicking search button the search bar should appear where it says basketball fanatico. how is this possible to do?

Comment: i am trying to use its class id to mess around with css but no luck not exactly how i want it. please guide. thanks

Comment: ^ in jsfiddle i got this working but in my actual code it won't work for some reason.

Comment: if i edit the js code n show u what i put in there will u able to tell me what i am missing

Comment: did you see the CSS in the fiddle?

Comment: hi @ezanker, i was just wondering how do you throw an error if a id that user enters is wrong. in my current program even if the user types in wrong id and clicks on login page they are redirected to page 2.

Comment: $("input[name='username']").val(), 'password':$("input[name='password']").val()}
I basically want to check to see if the id that user types matches the above 2 values and if it does then they can be allowed to redirect to page 2. can u please help on this.

Comment: if they don't match, just call alert() with a message and don't navigate.

Comment: how to do this? infact all i wana do is . if the user or password is wrong i dont want them to go to second page because right now in my app even if they type wrong uername or pw they can go to second page.